# Is it safe to use C# 8 feature 'using declarations' in a .NET Framework 4.7 project?

Tags: c#

.NET Framework supports C# 7.3, however we can change to different version.

Is it safe to use the C# 8 using declarations in .NET Framework project? It is a syntax sugar or there are changes in the runtime that will not allow me to use that feature in .NET Framework?

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? If it compiles, then it is fine to use.

Comment: @DavidG I can think of a few counter-examples to that statement, but yes: it is fine here

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh really, that's interesting. I'm curious as to what?

Comment: Net 8 is using CORE where the Net Libraries were rewritten.  So many Net 4.7 base code will not run without changes.  Core rewrote the OS interfaces and made lots of changes so code would work without changes on Windows, MAC, and Linux.  Libraries that do not use the OS usually do not require changes.

Comment: @DavidG off the top of my head, [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/64238) was fun - although it now generates a diagnostic, but for a while: it compiled fine, and blew up at runtime; there's also a fun `struct` + generics scenario which compiles fine but faults at runtime due to not being able to compute the size - probably where `struct Foo` has a `SomeOtherStruct<Foo>` field where `SomeOtherStruct<T>` is a `struct` - I can try for a concrete example if you really want - edit: ooh, that also now reports a diagnostic (CS0523); it didn't used to!

Comment: I have been using `latest` language version in various .Net 4.8 projects for quite a while now, and have so far not had any issue. But it is not supported, so how is your risk tolerance? Does *everything* have to be fully supported by some vendor? Or is it good enough if it compiles and runs?

Comment: @DavidG i am wondering if using this in .NET Framework will result in unwanted behavior. For example not disposing the object. If it is just a syntax sugar then it's fine.

Comment: It is sugar.  The tooth decay you have to worry about are the *other* v8+ features you enable by forcing the language version.  Which *do* require the CoreCLR changes, the compiler can't warn you about them.